# Downloading more than one picture from OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

How do you download multiple pictures from OneDrive into your computer?

I want my sister to have all of her wedding pictures that I took but OneDrive only lets me download one picture at a time.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to Windows Phone. Are you talking about the onedrive.live.com website? Or the OneDrive app on your computer? If the latter, which operating system is your sister using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the [OneDrive website](https://onedrive.live.com):

Each file has a little checkbox in front of it (in details view) or in the top right corner of the thumbnail (in thumbnails view). Use that to select multiple files, then click "Download" in the top menu bar to download the selected files as a ZIP archive.

Alternatively, you can also download an entire folder as a ZIP archive. Just select "Folder actions" → "Download folder" from the top menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Going to https://onedrive.live.com you can right-click on a folder and download it as a ZIP file. 
This does also work for shared folders.